# Cypress as UAT tool for Front end

Tags: cypress, uat

Hi All Cypress Geniuses,

So, I am already a fan of cypress and have comfortably automated my front end, integrated to Azure Devops, generated reports etc. All is going great.

What I would like to do now is to integrate Cypress to my front end. I want to give my end customers a dashboard on the same website where they can run the test (UAT) on there own.
Its a far fetched idea and not sure what I am talkin even makes any sense but would like to hear from you guys.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get why you want to give the tests to your customers, but anyway, can't you just hand them your Cypress test code and let them run it?

Comment: I would not recommend that. Cypress should be used as gate keeper before releasing a product, and not as a tool for an UAT-phase. If your customer decides that it wants to use Cypress in their acceptance, they should write their own tests.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. Ofcourse I want them to write their own code and tests. But I want to add cypress as utility(like an add-on). where they can just run the code without bothering to install/create libraries or node modules